# Django: copy queryset or get updated objects to update them twice

Tags: django, sql-update, django-queryset, django-orm

I've broke my head in attempts to update queryset twice

```
>>> users = User.objects.filter(source=1)
>>> users
<QuerySet [<User: 'Max'>]>
>>> users.update(source=2)
1
```

Then I need to update `users` again, but:

```
>>> users
<QuerySet []>
```

So, what options are available here?
Big thx

Answer (score 0):

User ids can be be assigned to a list variable first

```
>>> user_ids = list(User.objects.filter(source=1).values_list('id', flat=True))
>>> user_ids
[1]
>>> users = User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids)
>>> users.update(source=2)
1
>>> users
<QuerySet [<User: 123>]>
```